# Дублирование объекта ооп

Tags: php, ооп

Есть класс для работы с БД.
В файле я подключаю этот класс и создаю объект, делаю запрос и подключаю третий файл:

```
require_once("db.class.php");
$db = new DB(); // 1
$result = $db -> select("table_name", "row"); // 2
require_once("next.php"); // 3
```

В файле **next.php** всё тоже самое.

```
$db = new DB(); // 1
$result = $db -> select("table_name", "row"); // 2
```

Проблема в том, что если я снова создаю объект, то время выполнения скрипта удваивается, в общем с каждым новым объектом `new DB()` время обработки увеличивается на 1 больше.
Если не создаю объект, то всё нормально работает, можно сразу писать запрос.
Но кажется правильно было бы создавать свой объект в каждом файле?

Если что, в классе DB есть конструктор который подключается к базе и в конце деструктор:

```
function __destruct(){
    $this -> db = null;
}
```

Как было бы правильней и что можно переписать в классе, что бы можно было создавать свой объект в другом файле и при этом время выполнения не увеличивалось? Спасибо.

Comment: [singleton](https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794#file-class-database-php) вам нужен для работы с БД, а не устанавливать соединение каждый раз в новом файле.

Comment: @DmitryV. Этот класс работает с mysqli, а у меня PDO, когда у меня был этот класс с mysqli, то я мог удалять объект прямо из класса, а сейчас pdo и он почему-то не удаляет. Тем более, что в этом классе, что Вы привели в пример, в конструкторе тоже устанавливается соединение, как и у меня.

Comment: к сожаению не могу ответить на этот вопрос без кода. Может кто-то более сведующий в PDO придет и разъяснит.

Comment: @Владимир, а что мешает пример на pdo переделать?

Comment: @ВОРОН, так вот я же и переделал, что теперь такая нехорошая штука получается.

Comment: А что, сделать класс БД синглтоном сейчас уже плохой тон?  В смысле, уважаемый, а не сделать бы вам класс DB синглтоном?

Comment: Если я правильно увидел в классе синглтон нет ничего кроме подключения к БД, а в моём и выборка и всё что нужно есть. Не знаю, может я плохо смотрел)

Comment: Тот пример просто инкапсулировал логику установки соединения с БД. Если б это был не PHP, то там же можно было бы организовать пул соединений, например. Это все вопросы архитекурные, на которые единственного правильного ответа не найти.

Comment: @Владимир Синглтон нужен чтобы не плодить все новые и новые экземпляры класса. Он создает один экземпляр на все времена. и хоть вы миллион раз напишите `$db_1 = DB::getInstance; $db_2 = DB::getInstance; $db_3 = DB::getInstance; $db_4 = DB::getInstance; $db_5 = DB::getInstance; ` то все они будут ссылаться на один и тот же класс и у всех будет один коннект на всех.. а дальше с помощью этого коннекта вы вполне можете делать запросы. `$db_1->select("table_name", "row");` Вы просто не совсем поняли что такое синглтон и для чего он. Так что методы для работы с запросами никуда не деваются

Comment: Спасибо Алексей, посмотрю этот синглтон, но я уже вижу что в нём мало всего. Например не увидел как сделать множественный запрос, может плохо смотрю... Простите, ещё раз посмотрел и так и не понял зачем он, только ради подключения? В классе нет ведь ничего больше, т.е. зачем класс, если все запросы все равно писать нужно самому?

Comment: @Владимир что значит в классе нет ничего? Вы,видимо, смотрите пример который объясняет суть паттерна, в котором кроме его реализации нет ничего.**НО(!!!)**. Это такой же класс как и любой другой и вы имеет право написать там любые свои методы по реализации запросов.Т.е. в данном случае  у вас класс остается тот же, только способ подключения меняется не `new DB()`, а `DB::getInstance`.Всё.Если смотреть [ссылку](https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794#file-class-database-php) будет `$db_conn = Database::getInstance()->getConnection(); $result = $db_conn -> select("table_name", "row");`

Comment: @Владимир **[ВОТ](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php)** Вам наглядная сслыка реализации полного класса БД паттерном синглтон с методами для работы с запросами. или **[ВОТ](https://github.com/bennettstone/simple-mysqli/blob/master/class.db.php)** Хотя там конструкторы публичные, а должны быть приватные. но суть в том, что там все реализовано и классы не пустые

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я бы настоятельно не рекомендовал рекомендовать класс по первой ссылке. Его автор вообще не понимает, что делает.

Comment: @Ипатьев Да, я немного поспешил, не проверив всё. Но суть немного была в другом. Показать автору вопроса, что синглтон - это такой же класс как все остальные, а не чисто коннект без реализующих методов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже говорил, главная проблема этого кода - самодельный query builder и экономия на спичках. Читая этот код,

```
select("some_name", "some_name");
```

**ни один человек не поймет, что здесь выбирается и зачем.** А все из-за желания сэкономить пару слов в запросе и фантазий о том, что за две недели можно улучшить язык SQL, который разрабатывался 40 лет, но никто за это время так и не додумался сократить в нем ненужные операторы. Не говоря уже о том, что о безопасности с таким подходом можно сразу забыть.

Судя по всему, многие не понимают, чем отличается *настоящий* query builder, который действительно может иногда облегчить как каждодневную разработку, так и смену диалекта SQL, от такого вот велосипеда, который **всегда** пишется исходя из одного и того же предположения - что вся работа с БД сводится к выборке всех строк из таблицы. Со временем приходит понимание, что запросы вида `SELECT * FROM table` **вообще практически никогда не используются**, но автор остановиться уже не может. И функция начинает обрастать дальнейшими попытками заменить все богатство и десятилетиями выверенный синтаксис SQL на вызов единственной функции с анонимными параметрами, превращаясь в обсолютно неюзабельного и нечитабельного и - разумеется - небезопасного в использовании монстра. При этом совершенно непонятно, на чем строится уверенность, с которой разработчики подобных функций рассуждают о том, что у них "будут все проверки от SQL инъекций".

Синглтон в данном случае не нужен - созданный класс и так находится в глобальной области видимости и может использоваться во всех подключаемых файлах. Новый объект также создавать не нужно: создавать новый объект в каждом подключаемом файле - это все равно что держать в каждом кармане по бумажнику с одинаковой суммой. И в каждом магазине расплачиваться из своего бумажника. **Код в next.php будет прекрасно работать и без `new DB();`**, а идея создавать свой объект в каждом файле просто для красоты не имеет ничего общего с правильностью.

Тем не менее, синглтон для работы с БД действительно удобен. Вот пример [синглтона для работы с БД через PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/pdo_wrapper#code), который *действительно* упрощает работу с БД, не урезая при этом синтаксис SQL до двух операторов.

Comment: А я лично понимаю что написано в `select("table_name", "row");` что со мной не так? И это, в принципе, частая практика, делать удобные методы по работе с запросами, нежели вручника строчить каждый раз. Если это не сложные запросы

Comment: я бы не был столь критичным @Ипатьев.  Особенно вам припомнят все эти пары строк когда захотят сменить диалект с mysql на pgsql какой-нибдь. Принцип DRY тоже не  вчера придумали.

Comment: Спасибо Ипатьев, я уважаю мнения всех, но и у меня есть своя критика. Вы правы, можно использовать синглтон и не парится, но задача моя это сделать типа API для своей cms. Я реализую в своём классе так, что будет более чем понятно, тем более я конечно распишу всё перед публикацией. У меня в классе будут уже все проверки от sql инъекций, да и просто принципиально не люблю чужого. А на счёт чёткого ответа (идея создавать свой объект в каждом файле) большое спасибо. Если я правильно понял, то не будет ничего смертельного если подключать методы уже из созданного ранее объекта?

Comment: Хочу ещё добавить:
в каждой cms есть свои api, как и у меня будет. А на счёт того использовать его или нет в своих модулях или плагинах это уже его личное дело. Кто хочет пусть создаёт новое подключение если считает, что мой класс не приспособлен под его нужды.

Comment: Главное помните , велосипидирование вредно для здоровья , не стоит заного пытаться изобрести ДВС , лучше изучать зарекомендовавшие себя практики и использовать их в своей работе .

Comment: @Владимир тем более, если вы у вас своя CMS, то без синглтона не обойтись. Потому, что там должна быть одна точка входа и там просто **непозволительно** делать в каждом файле, где нужна БД - `require_once("db.class.php");` И от этого же коннекта можно питать и API

Comment: Спасибо всем, всё же я попробую поработать со своим классом. Главное что проблема моя решилась благодаря Ипатьеву, остальное дело каждого.